# OpenCV conflicts with Pytorch crop transformation

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, opencv

I'm building CV app using OpenCV 4.5.1 and torchvision 0.9.1. When I apply this transform

```
test_transform = transforms.Compose([
  landmarks.CenterCrop((512, 512)),
  landmarks.ToTensor()
])
```

to the image and try to

```
img = img.permute(1, 2, 0).byte().numpy()    
cv.circle(img=img, center=tuple(keypoints[i]), radius=2, color=(127, 255, 255), thickness=-1)
```

I receive an error from cv.circle()

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Without CenterCrop everything works just fine

```
test_transform = transforms.Compose([
  landmarks.ToTensor()
])
```

Transforms applied look like:

ToTensor:

```
class ToTensor:
"""Convert ndarrays in sample to Tensors."""

def __call__(self, sample):
    image, landmarks = sample['image'], sample['landmarks']
    image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    return {'image': torch.from_numpy(image).float(),
            'landmarks': torch.from_numpy(landmarks).view(-1).float()}
```

CenterCrop:

```
class CenterCrop:
  def __init__(self, output_size):
    assert isinstance(output_size, (int, tuple))
    if isinstance(output_size, int):
        self.output_size = (output_size, output_size)
    else:
        assert len(output_size) == 2
        self.output_size = output_size

  def __call__(self, sample):
    image, landmarks = sample['image'], sample['landmarks']

    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    new_h, new_w = self.output_size

    top = (h - new_h) // 2
    left = (w - new_w) // 2

    image = image[top: top + new_h,
                  left: left + new_w]

    landmarks = landmarks - [left, top]

    return {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}
```

**My question:**

How to explain this behavior of cv.circle(), given that everything except image size (reduced when crop applies) matches in images with and w/o applying CenterCrop transform? Thank you.

Comment: `cv.circle()` expects a 3-channel `uint8 NumPy` array as its first argument - Is your array of the correct data type? Check with `print(type(img))`

Comment: Two images are identical in terms of type and format of dimensions (HxWxC)